# MSSQL SYNTAX need to convert into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have the below Microsoft sql server query which I would like to run on MYSQL DAtabase.

getting the below error on mysql database:

> **[Err] 1064** - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Incident Num],tt.name as [Ticket Type],freetext2 as [Severity], tp.name as [Pri' at line 1

Microsoft Sql server query i am using:

```sql
SELECT t.tn AS [Incident Num],
       tt.name as [Ticket Type],
       freetext2 as [Severity],
       tp.name as [Priority] ts.name as [Status],
       title as [Description],
       create_time as [Created Timestamp],
       CASE WHEN th.state_id=15 THEN
       (select min(th.create_time) FROM ticket_history GROUP BY th.ticket_id,
           th.state_id having th.state_id=15  ) else create_time as [Assigned to Accenture Timestamp],
       (select min(create_time) FROM ticket_history group by ticket_id,state_id having state_id=4) as [In Progress Timestamp],
       (select min(create_time) FROM ticket_history group by ticket_id,state_id having state_id=3)as [Restored timestamp],
       (select max(create_time) FROM ticket_history group by ticket_id,state_id having state_id=2)as [Closed Timestamp],
       (select DATEDIFF(mi,max(create_time,min(create_time) FROM ticket_history group by ticket_id,state_id having state_id=12) as [Total Time spent by the ticket in 'Pending at user'status],
       cu.email as [Customer Name],
       customer_user.email AS Assignee
FROM ticket t
JOIN ticket_type tt ON t.type_id=tt.id
JOIN ticket_Priority tp ON t.ticket_priority_id=tp.id
JOIN ticket_state ts ON t.ticket_state_id=ts.id
JOIN ticket_history th ON t.id=th.ticket_id
JOIN customer_user cu ON t.customer_id=cu.customer_id
JOIN customer_user ON t.responsible_user_id=customer_user.id
```

please help me modifying the query syntax to ** MySQL** with out changing the logic.

Comment: I don't think this query would work in MSSQL. Perhaps you've made a transcription error. In any case, this query's hideous in any language, so it's probably best to start again. Consider providing DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle of a representative data set and desired result set.

Comment: Remove the non-standard quoted identifiers using `[..]`. Replace those identifiers that contain e.g. a space with a name that does not need any quoting. Then it should be fine.

Comment: Are you missing a comma... here... tp.name as [Priority] ts.name as [Status] ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are defining custom column titles, put them inside quotes(or in backticks, like so:

```
t.tn AS '[Incident Num]', // and so on
```

## OR

```
t.tn AS `[Incident Num]`, // and so on
```

The error is because of the same.

Comment: Thanks that worked .But again the same error : The error is on the line, where the "WHEN" starts.
Something within the CASE statement is throwing the error. the query runs, when I remove the complete CASE section
Please help me with writing the case statement in MYSQL

Comment: @user1424196: Maybe you should specify the complete error message. The CASE syntax looks fine to me, at least it should work in MySQL. I have doubts about your subselects, though. They seem potential of returning more than one row, and it would be an issue if they actually did.

Comment: @user1424196 Did you use the same for the `CASE` statements, where you have `as [Assigned to Accenture Timestamp],`